# Retrieve data from pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel. I want to show category A,B,C for article id(1). But it showing id numbers 1,2,3 for article id(i). I spend a few hours to get solution but failed. I want to know is how to code correctly. And another question is that it is right way to insert array to db using implode().

```
category table
--------------------
|    id | category |
|     1 |   A      |
|     2 |   B      |
|     3 |   C      |
|     4 |   D      |
|     5 |   E      |
--------------------

article_category ( pivot table )
----------------------------
| article_id | category_id |
|     1      |      1      |
|     1      |      2      |
|     1      |      3      |
|     2      |      1      |
|     2      |      5      |
----------------------------
```

HTML

```
@foreach( $categories as $category )
    <input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="{{ $category->id }}" checked>&nbsp;{{ $category->category }}&nbsp;&nbsp;
@endforeach
```

Laravel Store

```
public function store(Request $request)

{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|unique:articles|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category' => 'required|max:100',
        'status' => 'required|max:1'
    ]);

    if( $validator->passes() )  
    {
        $category = implode(',', $request->category);
        $articles = Article::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'content' => $request->content,
            'category' => $category,
            'status' => $request->status,
        ]);

        $articles->categories()->sync($request->category);

        return redirect($this->redirectTo)
                ->with($this->key, $request->title.$this->storeSuccess);
    }
    else 
    {
        return redirect($this->redirectTo.'/create')
                ->withInput($request->all())
                ->withErrors($validator);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you get the categories from the database? As well as your `Article` and `Category` model?

Comment: `$articles->categories()->attach($request->category)` is probably what you need but I don't see any reason why the `Article` should have a category column in it.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to define a relationship in article model with like so

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('ModelNameWithNamespace');
}
```

than you can access it

```
$categories = $article->category;
foreach($categories as $category)
{
    echo $category->{your field name};
}
```

Also you should specify relation from category to article the same way